# Spring.net 1.3.2 Xml config with Code Config

Tags: configuration, ioc-container, spring.net

I use spring.net 1.3.2 in my asp.net 4 web application, some component use xml configuration( I like that way because it's clear and all the object definition is in one place), but I also want to use 'code config method' to scan some assemblies and dynamically register some object, because it can reduce my work. (Castle Windsor did a better job on that!)
Anyone have some experience about that?
Thanks!

Comment: I have checked the spring document and google it ,but found no way. I wonder if there is a way to trigger a event after spring WebApplicationContext is created, then the job can be done.

Comment: Did you also look to [Mixing and matching configuration metadata formats](http://www.springframework.net/codeconfig/refdoc/codeconfig-context.html#d4e363)? I hope this will be useful to you.

Comment: I have already tried that, it doesn't work, I guess the problem is WebContextHandler:
 <sectionGroup name="spring">
      <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebContextHandler, Spring.Web" />
      <section name="parsers" type="Spring.Context.Support.NamespaceParsersSectionHandler, Spring.Core" />
    </sectionGroup>